# What does Oracle ASAP stand for?

Tags: oracle, oracleapplications

What do the initials ASAP stand for in the context of Oracle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It stands for Accelerated Systems Applications and Products.

To know where it will be used you can refer: [ASAP Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18887_01/index.html)

> Oracle Communications ASAP provides a convergent service activation
>   platform that automatically activates customer services in a
>   heterogeneous network and IT environment. It supports the activation
>   of consumer and business services in fixed and mobile domains against
>   network and IT applications. ASAP enables rapid service design and
>   network technology introduction by means of its metadata-driven
>   architecture, design-time configuration environment, and catalog of
>   pre-built activation cartridges to reduce deployment time, cost, and
>   risk. The application has been deployed for mobile (3G, 4G and M2M)
>   services and fixed multi-play (broadband, voice, video, and IT)
>   services in telecommunications, cable and satellite environments as
>   well as for business voice, data, and IT cloud services.

Comment: Thats incorrect. ASAP stands for "Automated Service Activation Program". In really simple terms, its an application responsible for converting high level network provisioning requests (for example from a CRM/order capture system to instantiate a wireless subscriber) into network device specific commands. In other words it a sort of translator that knows how to take a generic request and turn it into the language of the network.